# Need help - sideload android app onto a new phone

Tags: android

I am trying to get apps onto my new Moto G 2nd gen phone w/o using any Google app, including the only built-in browser app, Chrome.  (Yes, I know the OS is heavily Google.)

I have not yet installed my SIM card.  I used the built-in "check for updates" to get updated to Lollipop OTA direct from Motorola.

I connected the phone via USB to my PC and copied over the apk files for Firefox and Total Commander file manager.  But this phone does not have a file manager, and I don't otherwise know how to get those apk files to install.  Even when I put the apk's in the existing "Download" folder on the phone, when I use the "Downloads" app, the apk's don't show up in the folder.

Oh, and I do not want to root the phone.

So, any ideas how to side-load this apps?

Comment: People will argue that this is off topic as a goal, though oddly enough practical answers are on-topic as they rely on developer tools.

Comment: Thanks, all,  As for this being "off topic as a goal" and "oddly enough" - story of my life.

Comment: Off topic in the sense of user issues belonging on android.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
adb install <path_to_apk>
```

See the [docs for adb](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html).

Of course, USB debugging has to be enabled. The procedure for un-hiding the development settings differs from one device model to another, so Google the procedure for your device model.

Comment: Note that USB debugging must first be enabled, by repeatedly tapping the build number a bunch of times in settings-about, and then the developer menu will appear where the USB debugging can be enabled.

Comment: Thanks. I added a note in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could install Astro File Manager, that will allow you to view the Downloads folder and perform sideload.

You could also alternatively use adb to install the app using command line:

```
adb install MyApp.apk
```

Comment: This might make sense in the other order - use adb to install a file manager, and then use that to install other apps.